# Howto get STM32 MQTT exampel with STM32L496G-CELL02 and BG96 working?

Tags: mqtt, stm32, iot

I have the a STM32L496G-CELL02 with a BG96 module and I can't get the STM32 Mqtt example to work. Can sombody please give me a working howto? Attached is a little guide that I found but it doesn't seem to be complete:

> HOW TO include mqttclient application in IAR L462 and L496 projects
>
> By default the mqttclient application is not included in the delivered firmware. To include it follow the instruction below:
>
> 1. Remove "Exclude from build" option for the following components of the IART project
>
> - `Middlewares/ST/STM32_Cellular/Samples/MQTT`
> - `Middlewares/ST/STM32_Network_Library`
> - `Middlewares/ST/STM32_Cellular/Modules/MbedTLS_Wrapper`
> - `Middlewares/Third_Party/LiamBindle_mqtt-c`
> - `Middlewares/Third_Party/MbedTLS`
>
> 2. Define following Constants in `Middlewares/ST/STM32_Cellular/Samples/MQTT/Inc/mqttclient_conf.h` (To get these parameters from MQTT server account)
>    Note: These parameters can be defined by setup menu: At boot menu choose "Setup configuration Menu" then "Configuration: Mqttclient" and enter "URL", "username" and "password".
>    The other default parameters can be kept.
>
> To update:
>
> - `#define MQTTCLIENT_DEFAULT_SERVER_NAME     ((uint8_t *)"<TO_BE_DEFINED>")  /* mqtt server URL       */`
> - `#define MQTTCLIENT_DEFAULT_USERNAME        ((uint8_t *)"<TO_BE_DEFINED>")  /* mqtt server user name */`
> - `#define MQTTCLIENT_DEFAULT_PASSWORD        ((uint8_t *)"<TO_BE_DEFINED>")  /* mqtt server password  */`
>
> 3. only if stackhero-network.com then ROOT CA for MQTT Server authentication must be updated in mqttclient_conf.h (To get the certificate from MQTT server account)
>    Note: if the certificate is wrong only a warning error will occur and the application will work
>
> `#define MQTTCLIENT_ROOT_CA = {...}`
>
> 4. Remove other applications from Firmware (only L462 board because of memory lack) in plf_features.h :
>
> - Following variables to unset :
> - `#define USE_ECHO_CLIENT    (0)`
> - `#define USE_HTTP_CLIENT    (0)`
> - `#define USE_PING_CLIENT    (0)`
> - `#define USE_COM_CLIENT     (0)`
> - Following variables to set :
> - `#define USE_MQTT_CLIENT    (1)`

I also read here that you need lwip?! However, this is also excluded in the supplied example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use my library to work with MQTT via SIM800? Or fix it slightly if the set of AT commands do not match.
https://github.com/leech001/SIM800MQTT

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I appreciate your suggestion. I will try it later.